# How to have Spring Boot Filter just for URL that are mapped by @GetMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, filter

We have multiples web services all in Springboot rest. We use a filter to validate that a call to a service contains some required http headers and the filter will also put the values in logger MDC. I would like that filter to be enabled only for URLs that are mapped in my service with @GetMapping. For exemple, if a URL does not exist (returns a 404 not found) I don't want that filter to be activated.
Since my different services maps different URLs pattern, I cannot just specify the URL pattern in my filter (that filter is in a utility lib that services use). I want a solution that would work for all services.

Currently we have:

```
FilterRegistrationBean<MetadataFilter> metadataFilter(
            MetadataContainer metadataContainer,
            @Value("${path-exclusions: /swagger, /actuator, .yaml, /api-docs, .ico}") String[] pathExclusions,
            @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver") HandlerExceptionResolver handlerExceptionResolver) {
    ...
```

but this means that the filter is called on a 404 not found URL.
Is there any way to code this?
TY.

Comment: Which do you use? Web or WebFlux?

Answer (score 0):

One easiest way to do is to add annotation on your GetMapping annotated method arguments with `@RequestHeader(required = true, name="X-Header-Name") String headerName`.

Otherwise you can write your own implementation of `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor` and then only implement `preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)`.

Now you have access to request object and you easily check if the request is with method `GET`. You can easily find out with `request.getMethod()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sadly, in this case, the Filter does in fact more then just validate if the header is there. It reads it and put it in Logger MDC so the value can be written in logs. It's traking data. Also, we are in transition between one way of doing headers and a better way, so the filter will validate if the call has either the old header or the new header, and throw an error if at least one if not there.

Comment: Just finding if the method is GET would not work as any not found URL would also have a GET method.

Comment: I have added some clarification to my question